# Create sqlite virtual table in Python

Tags: python, sql, sqlite

I want to create a SQL-like interface for a special data source which I can query using Python. That is, I have a data source with a number of named iterable containers of entities, and I would like to be able to use SQL to filter, join, sort and preferably update/insert/delete as well.

To my understanding, sqlite3's virtual table functionality is quite suitable for this task. Is it possible to create the necessary bindings in Python? I understand that the glue has to be c-like, but my hope is someone already wrote a Python wrapper in C or using ctypes.

I will also accept an answer for a better/easier way of doing this.

Comment: I am interested in such a project myself. But Im puzzled by "necessary bindings". Isnt the SQLite bundled with Python not upto the task?

Comment: As far as I understand it, the Sqlite Python module can use extensions, but not define them.

Comment: Is the "special data source" you can query from python sqlite3, by chance? I've wished many times to be able to create a virtual table which wraps a generator that iterates over an sqlite3 query result, allowing to move from sqlite3->python->sqlite3 seamlessly, but there'd be some really devilish details to work out, I suspect.

Comment: It could be retrieved in Python, so yes, although it is not a pure Python collection.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do this by registering a virtual table in SQLite with the [APSW Python bindings](http://apidoc.apsw.googlecode.com/hg/vtable.html).

An example for [talking to CouchDB using APSW](http://code.google.com/p/apsw/source/browse/tools/apswcouchdb.py).

There's a similar capability for Perl, namely: 
[Create SQLite Virtual Table extensions in Perl](http://search.cpan.org/~salva/SQLite-VirtualTable-0.06/lib/SQLite/VirtualTable.pm)

Finally, if you want to make a Python-based virtual table in PostgreSQL 9.1, check out http://multicorn.org/.

Answer (score -2):

Sounds like you can use [SQLAlchemy](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/) to persist these objects to `sqlite3`, possibly to an in `:memory:` db, and issue both object and table level (raw sql) queries. You can also update/insert/delete them easily.

Comment: Unfortunately, the data set is way too large to persist like that with any kind of decent performance. Also, the data source is pretty efficient when it comes to filtering and sorting.